# How to prevent rails from changing the path when the edit action is rendered from update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As far as I'm aware this is the standard rails pattern for editing and updating a resource.

I have a GET route for the edit action on `/users/:id/edit` and both a PUT and PATCH route for the update action on `/users/:id`.

Here are my controller actions:

```rb
def edit
  @user = User.find params[:id]
end

def update
  @user = User.find params[:id]

  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    redirect_to @user, success: "Changes saved"
  else
    flash.now.alert = "Unable to change account details"
    render :edit
  end
end
```

And I'm using the default form_for in my form partial:

```rb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
```

which is creating the following form in the html:

```html
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/1" id="edit_user_1" method="post">
  ...
  <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch">
```

When the call to `update_attributes` succeeds the user is being redirected correctly, however when the call fails (due to ActiveRecord validations) the render action displays the edit view correctly, but the path in the user's browser changes from `/users/1/edit` to `/users/1`.

From what I've read it appears this is the expected behaviour of rails, but that seems confusing to me as I thought the core idea behind REST was that a URL referred to a canonical view of a resource?

If I `redirect_to` to the edit action instead of `render` then the url is as it should be, however I lose the error messages on the form.

Is there a more sensible way to persist the URL and the error messages than dumping the errors into the session before using redirect_to? I'd like to avoid that if I can.

**Update:**

The reason I want the URL to persist (as well as the errors) is because I'm using current_page? to set active states in the navigation. Therefore the 'Edit' action in the menu loses it's highlighting if the form is submitted with errors.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you were in `/users/1` is the view is rendered by `#update`, not `#edit`.

By default resource the path of `#update` is same as `#show`, with different request method `GET` and `PUT`. So, when `#update` renders HTML response, it's same as `#show`.

I think the result is acceptable, no matter what path your are in the result is expected. As you already found, if using `redirect`, the `@user` instance will be changed to a branch new one thus losing errors and previous fillings.

There is workaround on the path such as using session to pass instance variable, but I don't think it worth the effort. The current result is good enough.

#### Add

Manipulating active states is easy. I don't like `current_page?` which needs too much code. Use `controller_path` and `action_name` instead.

```
  if controller_path == 'users' && (action_name == 'edit' || 'update') 
     # add active class
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, however I need the path to persist in order to maintain the active state in my navigation, which is using current_page?. Sorry, I should have made that clear originally, I've updated the question accordingly. If using current_page? is for determining the active states for the navigation is bad practise let me know, but it seemed like an elegant solution.

Comment: @tommarshall, active class is not hard, there are lots of ways to get it working, check my update.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've implemented a solution for the active navigation based on your recommendation. I'm going to leave the question open though, as the question itself (how to render the 'edit' action from the 'update' action while persisting the url) is still unresolved. If I don't get an answer in the near future I'll accept that it's not possible and close.

Comment: A good reason for wanting to keep the /edit suffix is that if the user reloads the page without /edit it will get the show view instead of the edit one. Not exactly what a user would expect.
However if the page is rendered by update you won't get that /edit in the URL. You might want to PUT/PATCH to the edit action by creating that route for those verbs and checking the verb in the code of the action.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to redirect to the edit URL and avoid losing the error message by replacing

```
flash.now.alert = "Unable to change account details"
```

with

```
flash.alert = "Unable to change account details"
```